# How to get rid of the #func! appearing in a query table in ms access?

Tags: database, excel, ms-access, error-handling, ms-access-2007

I created a field called **Expr1** in a query to extract a particular string using the mid function from another field called **HOME_CARD**.

This **HOME_CARD** field has data like for example:

- IA1234
- IA6787
- KL8900
- MH5689

This is what I've tried to extract only the **IA** portion in my **Expr1** field and it works.

Expr1: Mid([HOME_CARD],InStr(1,[HOME_CARD],"IA"),2)

My issue is, I am getting the #func! error in my query results besides the data like:

- KL8900
- MH5689

In MS Excel I could handle this issue by using an **IFERROR** in front of my formula so where **IA** is not found, the cell would just be blank.

Please help me friends, I rather want my query result for those without **IA** to be blank(empty) than return a **#func!**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Left*:

```
Expr1: IIf(InStr([HOME_CARD],"IA")=0,Null,Left([HOME_CARD],2))
```